# How to deal with a big structure website performance

Tags: html, php, javascript

first of all thanks in advance for taking the time to help me out.

My doubt resides in how the performance is affected if I decide to develop a website only with html, css and javascript or if I decide to also include a database and php.

Taking into account that the website I am talking about is supposed to constantly create content and is planned to have profiles for over 100 people, in other words, it will have several blog posts and several profile pages.

So the question will be, will it be better performance wise to do this only using html, css and js, meaning there will eventually be 200+ html pages in the website, OR implement a DB and php will be better?? or it really doesn't affect performance.

PD: I know that if decide to use pure html it will be kind of messy if I don't properly structure the website.

Comment: How do you manage 200+ html pages website? Even it performance wise good, that is really bad idea... Just use PHP or any server side language.... There are tons of techniques to increase performance of PHP. Don't think too much

Comment: Is the website intended to be interactive? eg. Can users leave comments, rate articles, etc? There are several solutions available where you maintain the content in an "easy to maintain" database driven backend, but which renders a "high performance" static HTML site that your users see. Best of both worlds, but this can depend on the nature of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you value your time,  I know I wouldnt put hours of my time maintaining a 200+ html page website, above a couple of milliseconds of performance gain.  There are of course other options such as database-less CMS's like https://getkirby.com .

But you should always think about the future too, if there is the smallest chance of the site growing beyond the requirements of a html or database-less website...then its a better idea to plan for that now rather than additional work or cost at a later date .

Comment: Thank you for your time, indeed considering the time needed to maintain a website this big is a headache, and the performance gain if any wont be worth it.